# TikZ: draw lines connecting border of shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Being new to TikZ, I am trying to draw several (labeled) circles which are connected by lines. In its simplest form, I am doing this via

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.5] node (A) {A};
\draw (2,2) circle [radius=0.5] node (B) {B};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the connecting line reaches *inside* the circles which I don't want it to do:
[image]

How do I make the line reach only from border to border?

Comment: you can make those circles as nodes `\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm] at (2,2) {B};` etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As percusse commented you can draw circular nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1cm] (A) at  (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw, minimum size=1cm] (B) at  (2,2)  {B};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your code also works, but the problem is with how you've defined the nodes. I've added `draw,red` style to better see what happens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.5] node[draw,red] (A) {A};
\draw (2,2) circle [radius=0.5] node[draw,red] (B) {B};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, you are drawing two circles with rectangular nodes inside that are not drawn. And command `\draw (A)--(B)` works correctly, it stops drawing on node boundaries but not on circles boundaries as you expected.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the original code gives an undesired result.

Comment: Is`\path (0,0) node [circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] (A) {A} ;` identical to `\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] (A) at (0,0){A};` ?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs Yes, it is. You can even omit `(0,0)` because is the default starting coordinate: `\node[circle,...] (A) {A};`

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-node`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.35,-0.35)(3,3) % adjust the bounding box manually according to the contents of the pspicture environment
  \cnodeput(0.5,0.5){A}{Mammal}
  \cnodeput(2.5,2.5){B}{Fish}
  \ncline{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]