# Draw line to rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect a node with an edge of a complex shape. I am just able to connect it with the center.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm]

    \coordinate (S1) at (0,0) {};
    \coordinate (S2) at (3,4) {};

    \draw ($(S1)-(1,2)$) rectangle ($(S1)+(1,2)$);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(S1)-(1,2)$) rectangle ($(S1)+(1,1)$);

    \node (N2) at (S2) {blubber};

    \draw (S1) -- (N2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result image:

[image: Result image]

Comment: Which edge? Why not `\draw ($(S1)+(1,1)$) -- (N2);`

Comment: The problem is that your path goes from `blubber` to the `S2` coordinate which is exactly where your path goes. It's not pointing to the rectangle (which is not a node).

Comment: See also [TikZ: draw lines connecting border of shapes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211982/4778). Probably a duplicate but it certainly helps your case.

Comment: The line would not point to the center with `\draw ($(S1)+(1,1)$) -- (N2);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rectangles, use nodes. You can position their anchors, adjust width and heights, fill and draw the borders. Then connecting becomes very easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (S2) at (3cm,4cm);
    \node[draw,anchor=south west,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4cm] (R1) at (-1,-2) {};
    \node[draw,anchor=south west,pattern=north west lines,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=3cm] (R2) at (-1,-2) {};
    \node (N2) at (S2) {blubber};

    \draw (R1) -- (N2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You`ve won for a second ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution, but I don't like nested pictures, somehow.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm]

    \coordinate (S1) at (0,0) {};
    \coordinate (S2) at (3,4) {};

    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (N1) at (S1) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (-1,-2) rectangle (1,2);
            \draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,-2) rectangle (1,1);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \node (N2) at (S2) {blubber};

    \draw (N1) -- (N2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result image]

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s will certainly give headaches.