# What makes the line gets displaced?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What makes the line gets displaced?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1}]

\draw (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\path[fill=black] (0,0)  circle [radius=1pt] node[below] (A) {$A$};
\node[dot=B] at (1,1){};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another example of misunderstanding nodes size, borders, connections, ... Hope it helps. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211986/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line actually is not displaced, it got drawn where you requested it. When you say `node[below] (A) {$A$}`, tikz placed a node of rectangular shape (invisible) the size of the math symbol `$A$` plus an `inner sep`, it placed it `below` the coordinate `(0,0)`. Then, the `\draw (A) -- (B);` command just connected that invisible rectangle to the `B dot`. This is what your original code does (The rectangle is made visible here to see what I meant above):

[image]

Now, using a `coordinate(A)` instead of a node and the node text becomes the label of the coordinate, you get this:

[image]

Note also that the `dot/.style` is not equivalent to `circle [radius=1pt]`, the first is bigger than the latter by `.4pt`, the default line width, so you need to add that `.4pt` back to get the same radius.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1}]

\draw (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\path[fill=black] (0,0)coordinate [label=below:$A$](A) circle [radius=1.4pt] ;
\node[dot=B] at (1,1){};
\draw[shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is`\path (0,0) node [circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] (A) {A} ;` identical to `\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] (A) at (0,0){A};` ?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs - Yes, they are the same. Actually, `\node` is a shortcut for `\path node`.