# How to make arrow point to node in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Newbie Tikz question: I want to draw an arrow from a bullet to another bullet, with the arrow starting from and aiming to the bullets' centres, and I want the bullets labelled. This is my attempt:

`\fill(0,1) circle (2pt) node[above] (A) {1};
\fill(1,0) circle (2pt) node[below] (B) {2};
\draw[-latex] (A) edge (B)`

The problem with it is that the arrow is centred somewhere between the bullet and the label. I think I can see why it is happening: A is a node above the circle, so the arrow is starting from there. So perhaps the question should be: How do I turn the circle into a node, and how to label it?

Comment: Related/Duplicate?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211982/tikz-draw-lines-connecting-border-of-shapes/211986#211986

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, label=A] (A) at (0,1) {};
\node[circle, draw, label=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\draw[<->] (A) -- (B);

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\node[circle, draw, label=A] (A) at (0,1) {};
\node[circle, draw, label=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\draw[<->] (A.center) -- (B.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A `node` can take several forms. Default one is `rectangle` but you can also use `circle`. Charging `shapes` library you can get other aspects: ellipse, triangle, arrow, regular polygon, ...

If want to add a label above the node, you can use `label` option. If you want some text inside the node, write the text inside node's contents part: `{}`.

By deafult lines (or arrows) between nodes will stop at node's borders: `(A)--(B)`. If you want to explicitly join their centers use the specific anchor: `(A.center)--(B.center)`.

Comment: How do you position the label? For example, below?

Comment: Ok got it, thanks! You need to add a new node `\node[below]at(B.south){2}` to position the label correctly.

Comment: @Chrystomath: No, just write `label=below:B`.